# MEAN.JS Ver 0.4.1, Generators (CRUD) Not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meanjs

Installed Mean.JS Ver 0.4.1.

Updated bower packages and NPM Install on source folder.

when i try to create crud module using

yo meanjs:vertical-module customer

having following error

Error meanjs:vertical-module customer

You don't seem to have a generator with the name meanjs:vertical-module installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 0 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.

I worked with Ver 3.0 before never had any problems like this.

Attached image

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the latest version of the Yeoman generator does not yet have the sub-generators (like the one for `vertical-module`).

Refer [this comment](https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs/issues/119#issuecomment-141687239) on an issue for an issue about `vertical-module` on their GitHub repository

Comment: Thank you very much looks, generators for 4.1 are still under development. Thanks for the links

Answer (score 1):

this script may help you.

```
var=$1
if [ -n "$var" ]; then
    CRUDNAME=$1
    CRUDNAMEUPPERCASE=`echo ${CRUDNAME:0:1} | tr  '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`${CRUDNAME:1}
    FOLDERNAME=$CRUDNAME's'
    cp -R modules/articles modules/$CRUDNAME's'
    find modules/$FOLDERNAME -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/Article/'$CRUDNAMEUPPERCASE'/g'
    find modules/$FOLDERNAME -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/article/'$CRUDNAME'/g'
    rm modules/$FOLDERNAME/**/*-e
    rm modules/$FOLDERNAME/**/**/*-e
    for file in modules/$FOLDERNAME/**/*article* ; do mv $file ${file//article/$CRUDNAME} ; done
    for file in modules/$FOLDERNAME/**/**/*article* ; do mv $file ${file//article/$CRUDNAME} ; done
else
    echo "Usage: sh file.sh [crud-name]"
fi
```

It works for new version 0.5.0-beta